# hook_entity_update cancel

Tags: 7, entities, views, nodes

When updating an entity I want to validate that the fields I am updating are correct. As this may be coming from VBO or a Drupal form I thought I could do it in [hook_entity_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_update/7).

In hook_entity_update() is there a way to not update the entity and return/display a message.

Maybe I am coming from the wrong angle.

Comment: I think it would be better to handle it in the form validation. There you can throw errors and highlight the wrong fields prior to saving the entity (which you would do in form submit).

Answer (score 0):

The right hook for this job is [hook_field_attach_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_validate/7).

(As implemented by the [Field Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) module, which may also do what you want.)

`hook_entity_update()` actually fires after the entity and all fields have already been saved (in the case of nodes, at least).